# When and how to use withSampW in the function get.weights of the Package twang?

Tags: modeling, causality, propensity-scores, weights

I am using Twang R package in my analysis but I have doubt as to when and how should I use or not use the function `get.weights`.

The package documentation [here](https://rdrr.io/rforge/twang/man/get.weights.html) and elsewhere says `withSampW: Returns weights with sample weights multiplied in, if they were provided in the original ps or mnps call.`

I would appreciate any help to understand what that sentence means in practice and what are the statistical implications in the estimated weights and inferences of setting or not setting `withSampW = TRUE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you estimate propensity score weights to apply to a sample that has sampling weights attached to it, you need to account for the sampling weights in the propensity score estimation and the effect estimation. The way they are accounted for in the effect estimation is by multiplying the estimated propensity score weights by the sampling weights and then using these new multiplied weights in your weighted regression model. `get.weights()` with `withSampW = TRUE` returns the product of the propensity score weights and the sampling weights. `get.weights()` with `withSampW = FALSE` just returns the propensity score weights, which you must then multiply by the sampling weights before using in effect estimation.

Comment: Thanks @Noah. My data does not have any sampling weight attached to it. I estimated the PS but when I set  `withSampW = TRUE` the PS weights change. To what are the PS weights being multiplied then?

Comment: When I compare these two options using my own data sets, they are the same, so I'm not sure what's going on with yours. Are you positive you did not supply any argument to `sampw` in the call to `ps()`?

Comment: Thank you @Noah. You are right, I was wrong. Just one more question. I found the package `WeightIt` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WeightIt/WeightIt.pdf very straightforward and much easier to use. I wanted to know if the output of the `weightitMSM` function are weights for standard MSM or for HA-MSM. The reason is that I have effect modification by a time-varying confounder in my data and would like to use HA-MSM to do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WeightIt` is my package, so I'm glad you find it useful! I don't know what HA-MSM is, but it estimates the weights described in Robins, Hernan, & Brumback (2000).

Comment: Thanks @Noah. `HA-MSM` means `History-Adjusted Marginal Structural Models`. It is a generalization of the standard MSM to allow estimation of  `effect modification by a time-varying covariate`. Can the weights generated by the function `weightitMSM` in your package be used for HA-MSM? Thanks in advance.